# To use javaagent for a specific application hosted in tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, profiling, javaagents

I have a xyz.jar file containing premain class to get the execution time of a Java application in a text file. I have a web app (say myapp.war) hosted in Tomcat server for which I need to use this javaagent. I tried putting `"SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:/C:/xyz.jar"` in catalina.bat. I started the server but I don't find the required output.